# What could be cassandra schema to serve this query?

Tags: database, database-design, schema, nosql, cassandra

Assume a social application that has some million users  & there are around 200-300 topics, Users can make  posts which could be tagged  on upto 5 topics. I have 2 kind of queries on this data:

1. find post by a certain user
2. find all recent posts tagged on a specific topic.

For 1st query I can easily create the schema using superColumns in the User Columnfamily(in this supercolumn, I can store the postIds of all posts by user as columns).

**My question is how should I design the schema to serve 2nd query in Cassandra?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Justice's answer would work, I don't like it because it requires an OrderPreservingPartitioner to perform the range scan.  OPP has a lot of problems associated with it.  See the article that I've been [linking to constantly](http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/cassandra-randompartitioner-vs-orderpreservingpartitioner/) for details.

Instead, I would recommend this:

```
topic|YYMMDDHH: {TimeUUID: postID, TimeUUID: postID, etc... }
```

where "topic|YYMMDDHH" is the row key, each column name is a TimeUUID, and the column values are postIDs.

To get the latest posts for any topic, you get a slice off the end of the most recent row for that topic.  If that row didn't have enough columns, you go to the previous one in time, etc.

This has a few nice properties.  First, if you don't care about really old posts on a topic, only relatively recent ones, you can purge old rows on a regular basis and save yourself some space; this could even be done with column TTLs so that you don't have to do any extra work.  Second, your rows will be bounded in size because they are split every hour.  Third, you don't need OPP :)

One downside to this is that if there's a really hot topic, one node may receive higher traffic than the others for an hour at a time.

Comment: yes that downside was an issue due to which I was hesitating in following this approach.. is it really bad to have few hundred hot spot rows?? What are the other downsides besides undistributed load, if more, of following this approach. (I think its good infact since those limited rows could be cached easily in memory and that a single query would easily fetch entire data required data). Since I do not expect too much posts per hour I would prefer to store it split by days instead, thereby making easier to fetch posts.

Comment: No, a few hundred hot rows are not bad: all of your nodes will be busy in that case.  If you only had, say, 2 really hot rows, then one or two nodes would have a higher than average workload.  You are correct about caching; that's actually a nice advantage that I missed.  A small row cache would work extremely well for case, although if row cache is used, I would prefer to split by hours instead of days to keep the potential size down. (Actually, I think splitting by hours is better regardless.)

Comment: Thanks Tyler.... but regarding splitting..If there are very less no of columns added every hour, then anyways several rows would be required that would mean more row seeks (I think more row seeks means more expensive then looking within same row !!??Please correct me if I am wrong..) thus dont you think the correct answer to splitting frequency would depend upon no of columns added every hour/ day?

Comment: I suppose that's true if you expect to have only 0 to 10 posts per hour per topic; minimizing the number of seeks is always a good idea.  Plus, you could always switch from splitting by day to splitting by hour later if needed.

Answer (score 1):

For the second query, build a secondary-index column family whose keys are `#{topic}:#{unix_timestamp}`. Rows would have a single column with the post ID. You can then do a range scan.